# Missing checksum files when using Gradle maven-publish and signing plugins

Tags: maven, gradle, sonatype, maven-central, maven-publish

I have a Java project that makes use of Gradle to build and package. My purpose is to create artifacts that are published to Maven Central.

As a first step, I configured my Gradle project as shown in the following example from the documentation:

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html#publishing_maven:complete_example

When I run `gradle publishToMavenLocal`, I get the following files installed in my local repository:

> maven-metadata-local.xml
>   my-library-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar
>   my-library-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar.asc
>   my-library-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar
>   my-library-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar.asc
>   my-library-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.pom
>   my-library-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.pom.asc
>   my-library-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar
>   my-library-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar.asc

The files are all OK. The only issue I have is that checksum files (md5 and sha1) are not generated. However, checksum files are a requirement to have artifacts deployed on Maven Central via OSS Sonatype.

How can I generate the missing checksum files? It seems the *maven-publish* or *signing* plugins do not have an option for this purpose? what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I thought this was a bug in Gradle and I opened an issue, but as described [here](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/22482#issuecomment-1288767238) this actually mimics `mvn install` behavior. It sounds like Maven Local works a little different than a Maven Repository.

The proper way to test this locally is to use a file based repository. Since you're only using it to test (and not to actually share things with other projects) I think putting that into the build directory is best. Add the `repositories` section from below to the `publishing` block. Then when you `./gradlew publish` it will publish to your build directory.

### Kotlin

```
repositories {
    maven {
        // change URLs to point to your repos, e.g. http://my.org/repo
        val releasesRepoUrl = uri(layout.buildDirectory.dir("repos/releases"))
        val snapshotsRepoUrl = uri(layout.buildDirectory.dir("repos/snapshots"))
        url = if (version.toString().endsWith("SNAPSHOT")) snapshotsRepoUrl else releasesRepoUrl
    }
}
```

### Groovy

```
repositories {
    maven {
        // change URLs to point to your repos, e.g. http://my.org/repo
        def releasesRepoUrl = layout.buildDirectory.dir('repos/releases')
        def snapshotsRepoUrl = layout.buildDirectory.dir('repos/snapshots')
        url = version.endsWith('SNAPSHOT') ? snapshotsRepoUrl : releasesRepoUrl
    }
}
```

---

These two samples are actually from the link you shared. It's possible they were added later or you (like me) thought that `publishToMavenLocal` should behave the same as `publish` (apart from where the files actually go).

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was to use [shadow](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow/issues/718) along with `ant.checksum`:

```
tasks.withType(Jar) { task ->
    task.doLast {
        ant.checksum algorithm: 'md5', file: it.archivePath
        ant.checksum algorithm: 'sha1', file: it.archivePath
        ant.checksum algorithm: 'sha-256', file: it.archivePath, fileext: '.sha256'
        ant.checksum algorithm: 'sha-512', file: it.archivePath, fileext: '.sha512'
    }
}
```

Invoking `gradle publishShadowPublicationToMavenLocal` will generate the signatures as needed, although won't publish them to `~/.m2`.

At first I thought those signatures should have been automatic, so I opened https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow/issues/718 to discuss.